# PHP Scripting with Wordpress and Error Logs

Tags: php, wordpress, scripting

Cry for help here.

I have a fairly simple small wordpress site, but it takes forever to load. My hosting provider said, "The server itself isn't having an issue with any other users on it and seems to be operating fine and serving other sites without issue.  Almost every time an issue like this exists, where the load average is going over 500, it is usually an issue within WordPress that is causing the server to have unnecessary strain, which brings sites down.".

My developers can not find any issues with their code, and suggest that it is an issue with the root level hosting or WP install, not the sub-domain (where we did the coding). So, I'm trying to find the issue and need someone's help...

this is my first post, so I apologize if it isn't in the right format. - Adam

Comment: 1.Stop running your developers code and try to load your original site.if it loaded properly then problem is there in developers code. 2. if problem persist then try to deactivate plugins one-by-one and check if any plugin is causing the issue.

Comment: @NathanielFlick - That is not what SO is for.  This question will have zero value to future visitors with a link to a website that [gets fixed|goes down|goes away|gets updated|etc] in the future.

Comment: Please post your website errors to your question and we can help you. Fair enough, @cale_b, good point.